# Changing array element?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, element, computer-science

My aim is there is an array like this int arrMarks[] = {10,-15,25,102,30} and I need to make it equal to zero when an element is below zero or higher than 100. Then these elements should be in the last place of the array and the other one's position removed one place. So how can I do this without using any package or shortages?

```
public void validateMarks(int [] array){
        int [] array1 = new int[5];

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < 0 || array[i] > 100){
                int f= array1.length-1;

                array1[f] = array[i];
                array1[f] = 0;
                f--;
            }

            else if(array[i] > 0 || array[i] < 100){

                array1[i] = array[i];

            }
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void validateMarks(int[] array){
    int[] array1 = new int[array.length];
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] >= 0 && array[i] <= 100)
            array1[pos++] = array[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

#### Lessons to be learned here:

- Don't hard code values (`5` changed to `array.length`)
- Learn scoping rules (`f` and `pos` need to be declared outside of the `for` loop)
- Sometimes you don't need to store values

That last point hints that `array1` isn't actually necessary. I leave that challenge up to the OP.

Comment: then about the outcome because when I write         System.out.println(array1[i]); this it gave an error

Comment: and the other thing is in the second part we assign to the index 1 why not zero because it is the first index.

Comment: You misunderstand what `pos++` does. It increments `pos` after performing the assignment operation. `++pos` would be assigning it to 1, `pos++` still assigns it to 0. This is really just java syntax candy. Feel free to do `pos` and then on the next line write `pos++;`

Comment: I am asking a lot of question sorry but it gives this output 10 0 0 0 instead of 10 25 30 0 0

Comment: and it should be or not and because that way we can not find the solution

Comment: Just last question I understand the code but what part did you make this elements that are below zero or higher than 100 equal to zero :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the method swap.

```
public void swap(int i, int j, int[] arr) {
int t = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me check if I correctly understood it. As per I understood, you want to check each array value if it is less than 0 or higher than 100. If so, the value should be removed from the original array (replaced by 0) and copied into the last position of the new array. So, if I got it, there is my suggestion:

```
public int[] validateMarks(int [] originalArray){
    int[] returnArray = new Int[originalArray.length];
    int i,j;

    j=originalArray.length; //returnArray will be visited backwards

    for(i=0;i<originalArray.length;i++){ //originalArray will be visited forwards
        if(originalArray[i]<0 || originalArray[i]>100){
            returnArray[j] = originalArray[i]
            //Last valid returnArray's position will receive originalArray's value which, is less than 0 or higher than 1000
            originalArray[i] = 0;
            //The value which was less then 0 or higher than 100 will be replaed by 0 at the originalArray
            j--;
            //returnArray's counter is decreased so it can be visited backwards
        }
    }

    return returnArray;
    //The new processed array will be returned by this method. If you prefer, you can set this method as void and work it your way.
}
```

Hope it helps you. Cheers!

Comment: but in the terminal it gave and index out of bounds exception error

Comment: Ops, sorry. Change the line "j=originalArray.length; " to " j=originalArray.length-1; "

Comment: If it helped you, please accept my answer at this topic! Cheers!